# click select copy and paste it in the focused text field of whatever application is currently in front

Tags: apk

Click in one place to automatically select Copy. Click on the other cursor to automatically enter paste fill. That's just two clicks. Is there an Android app for that? It is best to copy, cut, paste, select, select all and other options can be enabled on demand within the Settings